# React production error with service worker: invalid MIME type

Tags: django, reactjs, nginx

I have a React app that works in development and in production, however in production I get the following error in the console:

```
The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
registerServiceWorker.js:80 Error during service worker registration: 
DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').
```

The error does not happen in development, only in the production environment. The app still works correctly in production, however I would still prefer to sort out the error.

After doing some digging, it seems that in production the `service-worker.js` file is requested from the original `index.html` file while has a MIME type of `text/html`, the `service-worker.js` file therefore does not have the correct MIME type which would need to be `application/javascript`.

Unfortunately even though I think I understand what the issue is, I haven't been able to fix it.

The production build was created using `create-react-app` and is served up by a `Django` backend. The `index.html` page containing the `React` app is served up as follows:

```
re_path('.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))
```

Is there perhaps something on `Nginx` that needs changing? I would guess not since I have other production sites working correctly with respect to MIME types (however none of them are `React` apps requiring service workers).

Comment: Did you figure this one out? I have the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I still don't know what the solution is. I have since encountered several other cases with the exact same issue. Hopefully someone will respond with an answer at some point.

Comment: Can we see your django configuration and whatever else is in front of django, like nginx? Also try opening the link to your service browser in your browser. Just navigate to that url. Do you see a js file or do you see index.html?

Answer (score 3):

It happens if you have registered some service workers. If you open Chrome developer tools you may get some errors.
Go to

> Chrome Dev Tools -> Application -> Service Worker

In there if you are seeing some service worker is registered then you have to unregister it by clicking it and after that refresh the page and check.

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that I have tried to unregister it without any luck – the error just reappears.

Answer (score 0):

From `registrationService`, I can see that:

```
    export default function register() {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {

        const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location);
        if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {

        return;
        }

        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

        if (isLocalhost) {

            checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl);
        } else {

            registerValidSW(swUrl);
        }
        });
    }
    }
```

When its production environment, then it tries to register to `registerValidSW(swUrl);` where swUrl is `<your domain>/service-worker.js`(FYI `PUBLIC_URL` is set from **homepage** value of package.json). But I am guessing that is not a valid path, so its getting `index.html` from Django. That might be why you are getting this error.

Again, based on guess, I think you can do the following solution:

1. Serve `service-worker.js` in from static folder (for example url could be: **/static/service-worker.js**).
2. Update in registrationService.js: `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js` to `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/static/service-worker.js`.

See how it goes. There is another solution if you don't want to use registerService in production, just not to register that service(I am not sure if its recommended or not, but its up to you)

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV != 'production') {
    registerServiceWorker();
}
```